# Yosemite server adaptive firewall doesn't start

Tags: macos, server, firewall

I run Yosemite server 4.0 and after fresh instalation i have tried to enable the adaptive firewall using the instruction here:
[OS X Server: How to enable the adaptive firewall - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200259)

After the first line I got:

```
sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf
pfctl: Use of -f option, could result in flushing of rules present in the main ruleset added by the system at startup.
See /etc/pf.conf for further details.

No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
```

I have tried also using this [Apple help document](https://help.apple.com/advancedserveradmin/mac/4.0/#/apd4288B31F-0C3D-4004-9480-4B7E0AFBB818).

```
sudo /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/afctl -c
sudo /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/afctl -f
```

After the second line i got this error:

```
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
pf enabled
Token : 1809440486742197081
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
```

My questions are simple:

- How to enable it?
- How to make it load on start up?
- And very important: How to check it's state (enabled or disabled)?

Answer (score 0):

Enable: sudo pfctl -E -f /etc/pf.conf

load at start up: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/214917/editing-the-system-library-launchdaemons-com-apple-pfctl-plist-file

check status: sudo pfctl -s info